# How to install the driver for iball 3.5G connect in ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, drivers, usb-modem

How do I install the driver for iball 3.5G connect wireless Modem in Ubuntu 12.04?

My Laptop is Dell Inspiron N4010. Modem is not getting detected.